# How to instant casting in eiffel

Tags: eiffel

I have following code in my do~end scope of some feature:

```
add (tempA, tempB)
```

Here, type of arguments are:

```
tempA: A
tempB: B
```

Both are declared as local variable.

And, here is prototype of feature add:

```
add (a: A; b: B)
```

The compile error I get:

```
Formal argument type: Generic #1
Actual argument type: detachable Generic #1
```

How can I instant cast type of "tempA" and "tempB" to Generic type from detachable Generic type? so that I can pass them to add feature.

I am not changing prototype, but I can change type of "tempA" and "tempB" though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until initialized the local variables are treated as detachable. They can be initialized either by assigning values to them

```
tempA := exprA -- exprA should return a value of type A
tempB := exprB -- exprB should return a value of type B
```

(e.g. `exprA` could be a formal argument of the feature in question) or by creating the objects directly:

```
create tempA
create tempB
```

(possibly with creation procedures, if necessary, i.e. `create tempA.make ...`).